# Can you read backward in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
"blahblah\dummytext\_config.bat"
```

If I wanted to get _config.bat out of this string, what would be the best way? Only way I can think of is read from .bat back to the first slash it finds but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Reverse input string, reverse regex patern, ... (:

But more seriously, /\\.*?\.bat/ would be the type of regex you're looking for. Or use something like /\\[^\\]\.bat/.

Comment: why don't you use the built path classes?

Comment: `/.*\\(.*)$/` then everything after the final backslash will be in capture group 1, dunno how to do it in C#. But yeah, use built in classes when you can.

Comment: Specifically, Path.GetFileName or Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension are the recommended methods for this kind of parsing; among other things, they support environment specific parsing, such as using "/" instead of"\" for a UNIX-based file path and will verify whether it's even a valid path string.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the last backslash with the LastIndexOf method:

```
int index = myString.LastIndexOf( @"\" );
string result = myString.SubString( index + 1 );
```

---

Daniel has a good point. Using FileInfo would be a safer way and is easy to use:

```
// myString doesn't need a full path either
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo( myString );
// returns just the file name without the path
string result = fi.Name;
```

---

And agent-j's hint:

```
string result = System.IO.Path.GetFileName( myString );
```

I was not sure if Path wants a full path or not. Both FileInfo and Path are also accepting non existent paths and file names.

Comment: If it's a filename, why use substring when `Path.GetFileName` would work?  +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

'$' matches the end of a line. So, this regex will match one or more characters that aren't backslashes at the end of line, i.e. '_config.bat' in your example string.

```
[^\\]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have everything after the last backslash, you can use the following regular expression:

```
.*\\(.*)
```

The capturing group will get you the desired result. Since by default the first .* is greedy it will match as much as it can and therefore consume also any backslashes except the last one (because then no match would be possible any more).

Comment: This would match nothing in the above string.

Comment: You have 2 forward slashes in your answer. Take them out and it does.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel It is almost standard notation to escape regexes within slashes. Even many languages directly use that notation.

Comment: Not c#, which is the language in question. Just saying, if the OP is having trouble with this kind of problem already, you might as well give him all the help you can.

Comment: @Howard: The problem with the "almost standard notation" argument is that only people who are already familiar with regexes know about it.  It's best to assume no prior experience and to provide the regex exactly as the OP will/should be using it--in this case, as a C# verbatim string literal: `@".*\\(.*)"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex way to look behind for the slash `(?<=\\)`:

```
string fileName = @"blah\blah\_config.bat";
Regex.Match(fileName, @"(?<=\\)[^\\]+$"));
```

But if you're talking about a filename, just use

```
string relativePath = @"blah\blah\_config.bat";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(relativePath);
```

Comment: Unless you're trying to filter out strings like "_config.bat" with no backslashes in them, that lookbehind is an unnecessary complication.  Anyway, we should be encouraging the OP **not** to think in terms of "backward" matching.  (Ironically, .NET does support seamless right-to-left matching, the only flavor I know that does so.  But that's not the right tool for this job.)

Answer (score 1):

Try RegexOptions.RightToLeft;  For more info follow this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx